# How to call a specific php function inside a class through ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I want to know how I can call the function `ajax_check_login` available in my `User` class, this class exists in `user.php`.
This is the basic content:

```
class User extends {
/**
 * Class Constructor
 */
public function __construct() {
}

public function ajax_check_login() {
    try {
        if (!isset($_POST['username']) || !isset($_POST['password'])) {
            throw new Exception('Invalid credentials given!');
        }
        $this->load->model('user_model');
        $user_data = $this->user_model->check_login($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);
        if ($user_data) {
            $this->session->set_userdata($user_data); // Save data on user's session.
            echo json_encode(AJAX_SUCCESS);
        } else {
            echo json_encode(AJAX_FAILURE);
        }
    } catch(Exception $exc) {
        echo json_encode(array(
            'exceptions' => array(exceptionToJavaScript($exc))
        ));
    }
  }
}
```

and this is my ajax request:

```
 var postUrl = GlobalVariables.baseUrl + 'application/controllers/user.php/ajax_check_login';
 var postData =
 {
     'username': $('#username').val(),
     'password': $('#password').val()
 };

 $.post(postUrl, postData, function(response)
 {
     // Some stuff..
 });
```

How you can see I want call the function `ajax_check_login` available in the `user.php` file. But I can't access directly to this function 'cause is located inside the `User` class, so I should create another file to bounce the request or I can do it in the same file `user.php` file?

Comment: Create a new file and make object of User class and use your function with the help of that object.

Comment: @Mr.Engineer as I imagined.. therefore all applications MVC is a rebound type functions.php file (example), that depending on the content passed from ajax request creates the instance of the class corresponding to the model, right?

Comment: @Dillinger you have asked this question already today, haven't you? What happened to that question?

Comment: same way you'd call it in the non-ajax context.   Ajax doesn't add anything special.

Comment: Do you have to have the "user.php/ajax_check_login" in the url or can it be "user.php?func=ajax_check_login" ?

Comment: @Gavriel I have reformulate the question in a clearer form.

Comment: I prefer this form `user.php/ajax_check_login` if this is what you mean

Comment: if so please also post the relevant parts of the routing code

Comment: @Gavriel I have no router class

Comment: Hint: if you add `print 'hello';` at the very first line of user.php and you go to `user.php/ajax_check_login` in your browser, what do you see? IMHO you'll need a routing or htaccess or pass the function name in a query parameter

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101921/discussion-between-dillinger-and-gavriel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo:

```
class User extends {
```

Extends what?

Add this to user.php (outside of the class):

```
$allowed_functions = array('ajax_check_login');
$ru = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
$func = preg_replace('/.*\//', '', $ru);
if (isset($func) && in_array($func, $allowed_functions)) {
  $user = new User();
  $user->$func();
}
```

Comment: are you available? I want ask you some question

Comment: could you join in chat?